# How to insert a carriage return in SQL SERVER SELECT

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert carriage return in SQL Select. I read a blog at http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/22/sql-server-t-sql-script-to-insert-carriage-return-and-new-line-feed-in-code/.

However this seems to work only for PRINT. How can I get it to work for Select.

Here is what I tried:-

```
DECLARE @lineFeed varchar(200)
SET @lineFeed = 'ABC, XYZ' + char(13)
SET @lineFeed = @lineFeed + '212-212-212 (bus)'

SELECT @lineFeed

RESULT:
ABC, XYZ 212-212-212 (bus)
```

What I need is this:

```
ABC, XYZ
212-212-212 (bus)
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Copy and paste the result into notepad. Newlines don't show up in the SSMS result grid, but they are still there.

Comment: Your query seems to work just fine: http://rextester.com/EBWUG88632

Comment: You must switch to text mode first (Control+T).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you view the results in text mode (Control T) you should see that your technique has in fact worked.